# set array as value in json format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to add array as json value.

Json format is as follows.

```
json_data = [
'name':'Testing'
'email':'TestEmail'
'links':[
'test@test.com',
'test@test1.com',
'test@test3.com']
]
```

How can I set value of 'links' in javascript like that?

I did as follows.

```
links_array = [];
links_array =['testing','test2'];

json_data.links = links_array;
```

I wanted to append these two string but couldn't.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: That's a syntax error. Are you sure it's not an object that contains a `links` array?

Comment: You probably meant to write `json_data = { ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the syntax of your example is correct, you can use the "push" method for arrays.

```
json_data = {
 'name':'Testing',
 'email':'TestEmail',
 'links':[]
};

json_data.links.push("test1@test.com");
json_data.links.push("test2@test.com");
json_data.links.push("test3@test.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make little changes to make it work.

First thing, You have to replace initial square brackets with curly one. By doing this your object will become JSON Literal - a key value pair.

Second thing, You have missed commas after `'name':'Testing'` and `'email':'TestEmail'`

Below will work perfectly:

```
var json_data = {
'name':'Testing',
'email':'TestEmail',
'links':[
'test@test.com',
'test@test1.com',
'test@test3.com']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `push` as mentioned by @giovannilobitos you can use `concat` and do it all in one go.

```js
var json_data = {
  'name':'Testing',
  'email':'TestEmail',
  'links':[
   'test@test.com',
   'test@test1.com',
   'test@test3.com'
  ]
};
var links_array = ['testing','test2'];


json_data.links = json_data.links.concat(links_array);

console.log(json_data.links);
```

On MDN's [array reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) you can find a more complete list of how to modify arrays in JavaScript.